how to get the user select text when using CodeMirror6 AutoCompletions
I am using CodeMirror6 autocompletion, I was wonder how to get the user select text when using auto completion? This is the code right now:
export function texAutoCompletions(context: CompletionContext) {
  //let selectedText = context.activatedCompletion ? context.activatedCompletion.apply : '';
  let word = context.matchBefore(/\\[\w\\]*/);
  if (!word) return null;
  if (word.from === word.to && !context.explicit) return null;

  
  return {
    from: word.from,
    options: [
        snippetCompletion("\\begin{#{1}}",{
        label: "\\begin{}",
        type: "text",
        detail: "env",
      }),
      { label: "\\section{}", type: "text", apply: "\\section{}" },
      { label: "\\subsection{}", type: "text", apply: "\\subsection{}" },
      { label: "\\usepackage{}", type: "text", apply: "\\usepackage{}" },
      { label: "\\footnote{}", type: "text", apply: "\\footnote{}" },
    ],
  };
}

how to get which commend the user select in current trigger or next trigger? I have tried:
 let selectedText = context.activatedCompletion ? context.activatedCompletion.apply : '';

but it could not works. I have turned on the trigger when user select auto completement code like this:
const texEditorState = EditorState.create({
        doc: ytext.toString(),
        extensions: [
            basicSetup,
            autocompletion({ 
                override: [texAutoCompletions],
                tooltipClass: ttc,
                activateOnCompletion: (com: Completion) => {
                    return true;
                },
             }),
        ],
    });

I have read this demo but it get the full document and I only want to get the autocompletion select text https://codesandbox.io/embed/vibrant-marco-p8znlj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark.
I also tried like this:
let s = context.state.selection;

still could not get the selection content.
